# How to get the image URL from LPLinkMetadata in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, metadata, swift5

I am trying to get the URL for the image associated with a given URL. Using Apple's `LPLinkMetadata`, I am able to get the URL's `title` and `description`, but I cannot figure out how to access the metadata's image URL. I have access to `data.imageProvider` but I am not sure how to use it.

```
import LinkPresentation

final class URLHelper {

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    static func fetchURLPreview(url: URL) {

        let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()

        metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { (metadata, error) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if let _ = error {
                    // handle error
                } else if let data = metadata {
                    let urlTitle = data.title
                    let urlImageUrl = data.????????
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check below my code for get image URL from LPLinkMetadata.

```
let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
let url = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/")!
    
    metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { metadata, error in
      if error != nil {
        return
      }
    
      metadata?.imageProvider?.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, completionHandler: { (url, imageProviderError) in
                if imageProviderError != nil {
                    return
                }
                let myImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: (url?.path)!)
            })
    
       }
```

Comment: Cannot find 'kUTTypeImage' in scope

Comment: @AndiAna `import MobileCoreServices`

Comment: Can you post full code to do this? i am not getting this to work properly... complaining about myImage not being used.

Comment: You are getting UIImage. Not the URL of the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
let _ = md.imageProvider?.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self, completionHandler: { image, err in
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self?.imageViewWebSite.image = image as? UIImage
                            }
                        })
```

Comment: i can't get this to work like this. how does it fit into the code above?